# How to update the textbox value based on selectbox using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I have two input boxes on my form.
One is a dropdown select and the other is the textbox.

I need to update the textbox value depending on what is chosen on the select box.
For example, if I choose "1" on select box, the textbox value should have "299.00" and if I choose "2", the textbox value should be "399.0"

Can you help me on editing the code? Thank you in advanced.

Here is my html code:

```
<select style="width: 25%;height:25px;margin-left:15px;" onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
<option id="extra1" value='1'>1</option>
<option id="extra2" value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<input style="width: 25%;margin-left:15px;" id="extraper">
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function ChooseContact(data) {

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var e = obj.id.toString();
        if (e == 'tb1') {
            x = Number("PHP 299");
            y = document.getElementById ("extraper").value = x;
        }
};
```

I'm sure that my javascript is wrong. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, your desired code is pretty simple; check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3Ljpeyk/

HTML:

```
<select name="extra" id="extraselect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="extrawrapper">
```

JS:

```
$('#extraselect').on('change', function() {
    var extraVal = $(this).val();
    if (extraVal == '1') {
        $('#extrawrapper').val('299.00');
    } else if (extraVal == '2') {
        $('#extrawrapper').val('399.00');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Id for the select and use the find getElementById() function to get a reference to your select

```js
function ChooseContact() {

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var e = document.getElementById ('myselect');
    var  selectedoption= Number(e.value)+1;
 var result= selectedoption+'99.0';
 var myInput= document.getElementById ('extraper');
 myInput.value=result;
};
```

```html
<select id="myselect" style="width: 25%;height:25px;margin-left:15px;" onchange="ChooseContact()">
<option id="extra1" value='1'>1</option>
<option id="extra2" value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<input style="width: 25%;margin-left:15px;" id="extraper"/>
```